# Kotlin Spring WebMvcTest Mockk

Tags: spring-boot, testing, kotlin, mockk

Has anyone encountered the issue where `@MockkBean` does not seem to actually work or at least the stubs are not coming through?

The simple example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [WidgetController::class])
class WidgetTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc
    @MockkBean
    private lateinit var widgetService: WidgetService

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val value = objectMapper.readValue<MyWidget>(something()))
        every {
            widgetService.getWidget(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())
        } returns value


        mockMvc
                .perform(
                        get(
                                "/apis/widget/v1/widget"
                        ).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect {
                    JSONAssert.assertEquals(
                           widgetPayload(),
                            it.response.contentAsString,
                            false
                    )
                }
    }
}
```

results in:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: WidgetService(com.bondhouse.pms.services.externalportfolios.ExternalPortfoliosService#0 bean#1).getWidget(test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always figure out the answer 3 minutes after posting ...

Make sure you are not importing the Mockito argument matcher with `ArgumentMatcher.any()`

Comment: If you use IntelliJ, you may exclude mockito  **auto importing** in for the project or ide scope. i.e. I exclude old junit packages. There are always naming conflicts between libraries :(

IntelliJ IDE's allow disabling auto-import and completition for certain packages in scope of IDE or Project.

`IntelliJ > Preferences > Editor > General > Auto Import > Exclude from auto-import and completition`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was `@MockkBean` was actually not working as expected(just creating a  mock but not injecting it). I dealed with this by manually overriding bean with mockk/spyk in `@TestConfiguration`.